# Parse an index which is a data series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, strftime

I need some help. I have an index in a pandas dataframe which is this column called: "Date Device value" (below)

I would like to split this index into different columns, so that I have a column for the date (the index), a column that says the day of the week and a column for the time.

I tried to use different methods with strftime to parse time, but it does not work.

It is a csv that I already transformed to have the date column as the index.

Thx a ton for your help!

```
DateDeviceValue                     
11/27/15 17:54  On/Off  Chaudière_logement  4.0 4.0 536448.0    On
11/27/15 17:54  On/Off  Chaudière_logement  4.0 4.0 536449.0    Off
11/27/15 17:54  On/Off  Chaudière_logement  4.0 4.0 536450.0    On
11/27/15 17:54  On/Off  Chaudière_logement  4.0 4.0 536451.0    Off
```

Comment: Could you please format the code/data section? http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column from the index casting it to a datetime, it may infer automatically but I prefer to specify the format exactly. (check my format string is correct)

Is your DateDeviceValue a datetime index? the values are identical?

If it is try this

```
df['Time'],df['Date']= df.index.apply(lambda x:x.time()), df.index.apply(lambda x:x.date())
```

else try this

```
df['Time'],df['Date']= df['dt_col'].apply(lambda x:x.time()), df['dt_col'].apply(lambda x:x.date())
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kickaha has answered the same, I would just like to add more to it as to how to start.

Make sure when you read the csv file, you parse the column *DateDeviceValue*.

```
df = pd.read_csv("foo.csv", parse_dates=['DateDeviceValue'])
```

Create two new columns by parsing date and time from *DateDeviceValue* column and delete it if you don't want it anymore. As you said you want date as index, set it as index.

```
df['TIME'] = df['DateDeviceValue'].apply(lambda x: x.time())
df['DATE'] = df['DateDeviceValue'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
del df['DateDeviceValue']
df.set_index('DATE', inplace=True)
```

Final dataframe looks like:

```
DATE      | A      |          B        |  C |  D |   E    | F  |  TIME
2015-11-27| On/Off |Chaudière_logement |4.0 |4.0 |536448.0| On |17:54:00
2015-11-27| On/Off |Chaudière_logement |4.0 |4.0 |536449.0| Off|17:54:00
2015-11-27| On/Off |Chaudière_logement |4.0 |4.0 |536450.0| On |17:54:00
2015-11-27| On/Off |Chaudière_logement |4.0 |4.0 |536451.0| Off|17:54:00
```

Comment: I would like to build a histogram that would show how many clicks on on and off are done at each our.

Comment: i posted another question on histograms if you can help?